# regex in homesite+ find and delete all before a certain <element>

Tags: regex

I'm using homesite 5.5 and I want to enter a regex in "extended find and replace" to find and delete everything (replace with nothing) before a certain element.

I was going to do it in two steps then delete everything after a certain element.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
<p> only save this and the p tags </p>
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

Comment: So, you want to just isolate that tag? Are you certain that the HTML will be clean? (no random spaces, attributes containing similar characters?)

Answer (score 1):

.*?<certain-element>

replace with: <certain-element>

Answer (score 0):

It's a while since I used HomeSite, so the syntax might be slightly off.  Basically you want the bit between your tags to use the ? so it's not 'greedy'.  Oh, and this will do it all in one step, no need to remove the bit afterwards separately.

```
Find: .*(<p>.*?</p>).*
Replace: \1
```